# How to get the href of second anchor tag which is present in second span tag of li. - Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

> I want to scrape the href of anchor tag which is present in
> second span of li.

```
<ul class="comp-contact" id="comp-contact">
   <li>
       <i class="comp-icon sdeqry hidden-xs sprite_wb"></i>
        <span class="mreinfp comp-text">
          <a class="lng_commn" onclick="_ct('sndenqrmail', 'dtpg');
                    openDiv('sbep');">Send Enquiry By Email</a>
        </span>
   </li>
            
   <li>
      <i class="web_ic sprite_wb comp-icon"></i>
        <span class="mreinfp comp-text">
          <a href="http://www.scarlehospital.com" onclick="_ct('weblink', 
                   'dtpg','','079PXX79.XX79.180129184951.U9X9');" rel="nofollow" target="_BLANK" 
                    title="http://www.scarlehospital.com">
            www.scarlehospital.com
          </a>
        </span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

> I wrote this code :
> But this will collect href from both anchor tags. I want second anchor's href.

```
def scrape_business_email(business_detail_soup):
    """ Function to scrape business email """
    try:
        spans = business_detail_soup.find_all("span", {"class":"mreinfp comp-text"})
        for span in spans:
            website = span.find_all('a')['href']
        return website    
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(str(e))
```

Please someone enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use CSS selector `span.mreinfp.comp-text a[href]`, which will select `<a>` tag with `href=` attribute. The first `<a>` tag doesn't have it, so it will be skipped:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<ul class="comp-contact" id="comp-contact">
   <li>
       <i class="comp-icon sdeqry hidden-xs sprite_wb"></i>
        <span class="mreinfp comp-text">
          <a class="lng_commn" onclick="_ct('sndenqrmail', 'dtpg');
                    openDiv('sbep');">Send Enquiry By Email</a>
        </span>
   </li>

   <li>
      <i class="web_ic sprite_wb comp-icon"></i>
        <span class="mreinfp comp-text">
          <a href="http://www.scarlehospital.com" onclick="_ct('weblink',
                   'dtpg','','079PXX79.XX79.180129184951.U9X9');" rel="nofollow" target="_BLANK"
                    title="http://www.scarlehospital.com">
            www.scarlehospital.com
          </a>
        </span>
   </li>
</ul>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('span.mreinfp.comp-text a[href]')['href'])
```

Prints:

```
http://www.scarlehospital.com
```

Comment: Nice! Learned something there myself.

Comment: You told above that  first <a> have not href , so it is printing the href from second <a>. But what if first <a> have href...?

Comment: @HemantSah You can use, for example, CSS selector `span.mreinfp.comp-text a:nth-child(2)` to get second child

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thankyou again, I get this. I need to work more on these child things ️

Comment: @AndrejKesely The second code you suggested is not working for me... can you tell me more accurately little bit

Comment: @HemantSah Can you edit your question and post there sample of HTML code?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Well, I have solved this:   

`website = business_detail_soup.select('span.mreinfp > a')[1]
    return website['href']`

Comment: Above code gives me exactly the href of second <a> tag. Thankyou for your help @AndrejKesely

Answer (score 1):

```
soup_links = business_detail_soup.select("span.mreinfp comp-text > a")
for a in soup_links:
    link = a['href']
```

The alternative would be

```
link = business_detail_soup.select("span.mreinfp comp-text:nth-child(2) > a")['href']
```